# Rendering newline charactors from variable in Twirl

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, twirl

I have a toy Play framework project. And my Java code is something like:

```
    String r = "apple\nbanana";
    return ok(index.render(r));
```

And my index.scala.html is something like

```
@(r: String)

<table border="1" style="width:98%">
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>@r</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

The problem is that, in the displayed html, the newline character is gone. I want to get two lines in html but only get one line.

I even tried changing the line in Java to something like:

```
 String r = "apple<br>banana";
```

But the html still shows one line instead of two lines,
It just shows

```
"apple<br>banana"
```

So how can I get two lines (making the newline character work) in Twirl?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be default, Twirl escapes all HTML tags from the dynamic content. If you want to render tags from a variable you can use **@Html()**. In your case it would be like this:

```
@(r: String)

<table border="1" style="width:98%">
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>@Html(r)</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Obviously the new line character doesn't work because browsers ignore white spaces while rendering HTML output.